# hovering over multiple divs

Tags: html, css

i have 6 divs I want to zoom the div I am currently active on
My code is:

```css
#section1,#section2,#section3 ,#section4,#section5,#section6{
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background:#41aacc;
            margin:20px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        #wrapper{
            width:60%;
            margin:0 auto;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content:center;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="section1">
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
    </div>
    <div id="section4">
    </div>
        <div id="section5">
    </div>
        <div id="section6">
    </div>
        </div>
```

i do not want to use multiple selector like `#selector1:hover{transform:scale(1.1)}`and so on .How can I achieve it without iterating it for all the divs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you can't use `#wrapper div:hover` ?

Comment: @MarianIoan I mostly agree but `#wrapper > div:hover` would be better. Deeper nested divs won't get affected then.

Comment: @LukeBriggs That's true. I assumed that he will be using this technique for an image, and it wouldn't be a deeper nesting. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write

```css
div[id^="section"] {...}
```

this selector will get all of divs with id value starting with "section"

or more specific

```css
#wrapper > div[id^="section"] {...}
```

Look at snippet

```css
#wrapper > div[id^="section"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #41aacc;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
#wrapper{
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#wrapper > div[id^="section"]:hover 
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="section1">
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
    </div>
    <div id="section4">
    </div>
        <div id="section5">
    </div>
        <div id="section6">
    </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS class.  The following applies the transformation to all block elements directly under the "wrapper" div.

CSS:

```
#wrapper div {
  // applies to all divs under wrapper.
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#41aacc;
  margin:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#wrapper .hoverable:hover {
  // applies only to "hoverable" class items when hovered.
  transform:scale(1.1)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="section1" class="hoverable"></div>
  <div id="section2" class="hoverable"></div>
  <div id="section3" class="hoverable"></div>
  <div id="section4" class="hoverable"></div>
  <div id="section5" class="hoverable"></div>
  <div id="section6" class="hoverable"></div>
</div>
```